# Template engine in .NET

Tags: .net

I am looking for a template engine to be used in .NET.
Coming from python, I know jinja, but I was not able to find anything similar. My use case is to create SQL queries starting from vb.net objects containing information on which columns to take (eventual aliases), which tables to join...

Comment: Not familiar with python, but what you describe sounds like ORM. You can have a look on Dapper or EntityFramework.

Comment: Not really looking for an ORM, it would be too heavy from what I would like to do. I will give a look at what you suggest (thanks) and also I will try to provide an example for what I am looking for.

Comment: I've looked on Jinja (there are more meaning to "templating engine" than what it is meant here). Alternative in .Net would be Razor and [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) as a stand-alone.

Comment: To add to @trailmax' suggestion, Razor with Linq seems to do with jinja does, albeit probably more verbose and comes with a few "don't do it"'s attached - See https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/64656/is-it-legit-to-use-a-linq-query-in-a-razor-view . It should be noted that I'm not familiar with jinja apart from a quick google search.

Comment: @trailmax: thanks for the suggestion, from a first look at RazorEngine, it seems to be what I am looking for!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a templating engine in .NET called Scriban (https://github.com/lunet-io/scriban), written in C#. While it was directly inspired by Shopify's *liquid* templating (originally written in Ruby) which is quite similar, at least in spirit, to Jinja, the author of Scriban [actually admits](https://xoofx.com/blog/2017/11/13/implementing-a-text-templating-language-and-engine-for-dotnet/) to have been strongly influenced by Jinja.

I have subsequently extended Scriban to include things like *layouts* (which are called *template inheritance* in Jinja) and *sections* (called *blocks* in Jinja). My extension is called Scriptic and lives [here on GitHub](https://github.com/optimax/scriptic). This is the closest thing to Jinja (the Pythonic templating engine) I know on .NET.

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely the perfect answer for my question! Now I just have to get back to actually go back to my use case and put it to work, but I hope it will be helpful for others to! ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could try using T4, which is specifically meant to generate code given some text inputs. It is supported in Visual Studio.

Here are some links to get started

- [Code Generation and T4 Text Templates](https://www.bing.com/search?q=t4%20template&PC=U316&FORM=CHROMN)
- [Scott Hanselman blog post](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx)